# Получить View неактивной страницы ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: нужно получить `View` неактивной страницы `ViewPager'а`. Пробовал сохранять их при создании `onCreateView` в классе `PagerFragment` в массив и давал тэги, но, при обращении к странице, отличной от текущей, возвращается `NullPointerException`. Решил проблему огромным костылем: делал перебор страниц в `ViewPager` методом `setCurrentItem()`, но это не решение проблемы.

Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
static Context ctxt = null;
public MyAdapter(Context ctxt, FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
    this.ctxt=ctxt;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return(7);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return(PageFragment.getTitle(ctxt, getDay(position)));
}

private String getDay(int position)
{
    return GlobalVariables.days[position];
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return ctxt;
}
}
```

PageFragment

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

private int pageNumber;

public static View vArr[] = new View[7];

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", page);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public PageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
}

static String getTitle(Context ctxt, String day) {
    return day;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    ListView lstV = (ListView) result.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //Действия опущены
    vArr[pageNumber] = result;
    return result;
}
}
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: а какая цель данного действия? если view невидим, то он может не существовать и получения NullPointerException вполне логично.

Comment: Опишите лучше что надо сделать, а не как дописать плюшку к костылю

Comment: @АндроидАндроид есть ViewPager с 7 страницами. Нужно обновить на каждой из них ListView, оставаясь на текущей странице.

Comment: не нужно обновлять ListView. Нужно обновить объекты, из которых потом адаптеры для нужных ListView возьмут данные.

Comment: @KoVadim но мне же нужно как-то получить эти ListView для этого.

Comment: нет. не нужно. Когда пользователь перейдет на нужную вкладку, listview будет создано и данные подгрузятся с адаптера. До тех пор, пока пользователь не видит ListView, менять его нет смысла.

Comment: @KoVadim немного не дописал. Есть 2 списка. По умолчанию ListView берет данные из первого. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки он поменял список на другой и обратно. А для этого, как я понял. нужно создавать новый адаптер.

Comment: либо создавать новый адаптер, либо адаптер должен уметь переключать списки.

Comment: @KoVadim а если создать промежуточный список, который будет принимать значения то одного, то другого списка, и обновлять его, то адаптер заново создавать не нужно будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы не было уничтожения неактивных View поставьте

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(@кол-во экранов);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Именно то, что было нужно.

Comment: Единственное, в чем заключается небольшая проблема, это то, что после обновления меняется цвет шрифта на белый. Помогает добавление-удаление элемента в список.